# How do I let Jade(pug) included file access the variable?

Tags: pug

Hi have two jade (now called pug) templates:

- page.jade
- portion.jade

In page.jade, the code is like:

```
// page.jade
include portion.jade
script.
  var text = "#{var}"; // will convert to the variable I passed in.
```

The `#{var}` part will be successfully converted to the content I desired.

However, if I put this line in the portion.jade, it would fail:

```
// portion.jade
script.
  var text = "#{var}"; // fails to convert, remains #{var}
```

How can I access the variable in the included jade file?

Answer (score 1):

When you put the variable into a `script` element then you are sending this out as JavaScript to the browser.  If you view source in the rendered page you will see this:

```
<script>
  var text = "#{var}";
</script>
```

Instead, you want to use a `-` to [escape your code](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html) to use this variable inside the template:

```
- var text = "#{var}";
```

Note that there is no `script.` tag there.

However, something tells me that another problem will pop up once you solve this one.  That string will not be further evaluated by pug, it will be output as a string.

I would strongly recommend that you sort out all of your variables in the route and not try to do something tricky in your templates or included files.  In my experience, creating variables inside templates is rarely necessary, often leads to errors, and can be difficult to debug.